# Unable to start phantomjs with ghostdriver

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs

I am running a code that has `selenium` component, which requires `phantomJS`.
I am getting the following error message:
 `Unable to start phantomjs with ghostdriver.' ; Screenshot: available`

In my code, I specified my `phantomJS` path(the `bin` path), but such measure didn't work.
I have placed the `phantomJS-osx` folder at the same location as my folder for `selenium` - would it be the cause of my problem?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what version of Ghostdriver you are on, but I got that error on 1.9.7 until I upgraded to selenium 2.40

Answer (score -2):

This is a bug. Please use selenium 2.37.2